# COMException during saving .lnk file on desktop

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop

My application throws

> 

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

when saving .lnk file on desktop. Here's the code saving the shortcut:

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            var startupFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var shell = new WshShell();
            var windowsApplicationShortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(startupFolderPath);
            windowsApplicationShortcut.Description = "Network Folder";
            windowsApplicationShortcut.WorkingDirectory = @"Z:\";
            windowsApplicationShortcut.TargetPath = @"Z:\";
            windowsApplicationShortcut.IconLocation = Application.StartupPath + @"\img\normal.ico";
            windowsApplicationShortcut.Save(); // this line throws exception
        }
```

- My desktop isn't read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var windowsApplicationShortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(startupFolderPath);`

`startupFolderPath` should include the shortcut file name but not just the folder path which will contain the shortcut file. [MSDN ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys(v=vs.85).aspx)

**UPDATE:**

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            var startupFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var inkRef = startupFolderPath  + @"\img\normal.ico";
            var shell = new WshShell();
            var windowsApplicationShortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(inkRef);
            windowsApplicationShortcut.Description = "Network Folder";
            windowsApplicationShortcut.WorkingDirectory = @"Z:\";
            windowsApplicationShortcut.TargetPath = @"Z:\";
            windowsApplicationShortcut.IconLocation = Application.StartupPath + @"\img\normal.ico";
            windowsApplicationShortcut.Save(); // this thrown error
        }
```